# Not able to connect my local system client socket to cloud based socket server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-sockets

**Below is my server.py file which runs on cloud based ubuntu system.**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5555

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

print("Server started host={} port={}".format(host, port))

while True:
    print('>>>>>>>>>> inside the while')
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Got connection from", addr)
    c.send(bytes("Thank you", "utf-8"))
```

**Now the below is my local system client.py file :**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('my_cloud_server_ip/ssh',5555))
s.recv(1024)
```

**Error which I am getting this:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

So is there anything wrong with the code or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does /ssh mean? Is your string like '1.2.3.4/ssh' or is it just '1.2.3.4'? Can you connect with netcat? Did you open port 5555 in the cloud's firewall?

Comment: no it just '1.2.3.4' , and yes i opened the port on my local windows machine because i want to connect the socket from cloud to local system as my server.py runs at local system that's why @user253751

Comment: And for netcat as you said, can you tell me @user253751 that where i need to apply that command at server side or client side ?

Comment: Does your local machine's IP address happen to start with 192.168 or with 10?

Comment: I am using the public ip of that local system which start from 46. @user253751

Comment: Does the code work locally? Just to verify it actually works before looking into the network part.

Comment: Yes @Karl locally it works completely fine.

Comment: So then it is a network issue then. What user253751 meant with netcat is that you can use the tool to try and access your ip:port just to see if the port is open from the clouds point of view. Do you have access to a terminal in the cloud machine to try netcat? `netcat <ip for mycloud_server_ip/ssh> 5555`

Comment: Yes @Karl i checked and that works.

Comment: What's the IP address that server.py binds to?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to all networks by setting `host='0.0.0.0'`.

In general I suggest you follow this tutorial [Socket Programming in Python (Guide)](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) to use `with` for starting connections and such.

Comment: Thanks Karl but that will not work for me because i already did that before.